# How to get fastball pitches over 150 km/h in wii sports (baseball)?

Tags: wii-sports

I once got fastball pitch of 150 km/h (93 mph) in the baseball game of Wii Sports. I only did it only once, all my other fastball are much slower than that usually 100 mph (62 mph).

I don't know how I was able to throw a pitch like that. I don't remember what technique did I used. I would like to know which motion or pitching mechanic I need to achieve these speeds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick to ultra-fast pitches is a fast, but short movement, like [flicking your wrist](http://www.ehow.com/how_2237448_extrafast-pitches-wii-sports-baseball.html):

> Quickly flick your wrist instead of throwing an actual pitch. This is the catch: quickly flicking your wrist will make the controller think you're making the "throw" motion a lot faster than you actually are.

Another tip compared it to trying to [swat a fly](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090530092403AAExrYy) - a sharp downward motion.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the best method is to kinda throw a direct punch (as if boxing), which 95% of the time results in 150-153km/h fast balls.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Comment: @Texenox - It actually does

Comment: @Robotnik, sorry, was just difficult to make out without it being edited.

Comment: @Texenox - The last sentence wasn't, which is why I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to flick your wrist and depending on how fast you flick your wrist, it will normally result in 93/94 miles an hour.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).